# Restoring the wchar.h c++ include file

Tags: c++, linux, include

I was trying to apply a patch which would allow me to use `std::to_string()`. I used rm on the `/usr/include/wchar.h` and then copied the patched `wchar.h` that I downloaded to the /usr/include directory. Now when I attempt to compile programs, it complains that it can't find `_mingw.h`

At this point, I would just like to find a way to get a copy of the old `wchar.h` and replace the "patched" one. I'll just find a way to do it without `std::to_string();`

Comment: The ***only*** person allowed to use the internet as his personal backup is Linus Torvalds. Linus, is that you?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this has little to do with programming, so it is probably off-topic here. However...

Firstly: Serves you right. Yes. You have been working with root privileges but without taking proper care not to break your system. There's a reason there's a separate root account, don't use it for everyday work.

Secondly, there are ways to fix this, but they depend a bit on the system. Start with finding out which package installed that header and then reinstall the whole package. You could also try to extract and restore just that file, but that's probably more complicated. For example under Debian, run `dpkg -S /usr/include/wchar.h` to find out which package installed that file, libc6-dev in this case. Then, use `apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev` to reinstall the package, which should fix your problem.

Lastly, to get back to programming, your approach is flawed. The standard header files are usually not portable between different compilers. Also, they might declare functionality that is implemented in separate libraries which are even less portable. My suggestion: Ask a new question where you specifically detail what you want to achieve and on which system.